# Does RxJava's onBackpressureDrop() drop items?

Tags: rx-java

I tried below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  Observable.interval(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .onBackpressureDrop().subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
      request(1L);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNext(Long t) {
      System.out.println("received: " + t);
      try {
        Thread.sleep(1000L);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      request(1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompleted() {
      System.out.println("onCompleted");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  });

  TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(10L);
}
```

I expected that the subscriber would receive the item `0, 10, 20, 30...` because onBackpressureDrop method would drop the items before the request.
But the result was `0, 1, 2, 3...`.

Also, I tried `onBackpressureLatest()` but the result was the same, `0, 1, 2, 3...`.

This seem to me the same as `onBackpressureBuffer`.

Do I misunderstand this method?
If so, how I tried that onBackpressureDrop method would work as the marble diagram in Javadoc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onBackpressureDrop` doesn't do anything here because in this particular case there is no 'backpressure'. What you do in the `subscribe` method is block the thread on which new values are created by the `Observable.interval` method by sleeping for 1 second after each emission. Therefore the `Observable.interval` does not generate a value every 100 milliseconds but is forced to do this only once per second!

I suggest you to put an `observeOn` between the `onBackpressureDrop` and `subscribe` such that generating of values and the things you do in the `subscribe` are on different threads. To see the effect, use [this overload](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#observeOn(rx.Scheduler,%20int)) with a small buffer size (eg. 1). Any kind of Scheduler will do as far as I know.

Comment: I tired and I got what I want. So, the problem is that I also blocked the emission. Now, I understand. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because you put thread on which interval() is operating to sleep. One possible solution - adding observeOn(Scheduler,bufferSize) operator:

```
  Observable.interval(100L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .onBackpressureDrop()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io(), 1)
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {

                @Override
                public void onStart() {
                    request(1L);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(Long t) {
                    System.out.println("received: " + t);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000L);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    request(1);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    System.out.println("onCompleted");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

    Observable.empty().delay(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES).toBlocking().subscribe();
```

That way your subscriber  operates on io() scheduler with minimal buffer size, and backpressure seems to work:

received: 0
received: 11
received: 22

Comment: I tried and I got what I want. Thank you for your help! Also, I noticed that if I put bufferSize in `observeOn`, I don't have to call `request` in Subscriber. It looks like that `observeOn` method with buffer size would call Subscriber's `request` method inside.